# Build Apk with a large zip

Tags: android, android-studio

I am working on a project that has a zip files to the assets, My zip file was 4 Mb and everything was alright. Now after a change request I had to add more files to this zip and his size now is 300 Mb. I don't know the reason but know Android Studio is not building an Apk anymore, Gradle build starts running but does not stop. Please if anyone can give me an answer how to fix this issue
Thanks a lot

Comment: Bear in mind that you cannot ship an APK that large via the Play Store. If you are using some other distribution channel, please double-check its size limits.

Comment: You can use **expansion files**, when distributing large data.

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for your reply, can you please help me with an example of that?

Comment: An example of **what**?

Comment: @CommonsWare  I solved the problem by separating the large zip into different zips, thank you